# Is it ok to use both MaterialUI and antd in one app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd

I was writing an application with MaterialUI components and have a lot of things so far. Then I found this great landing page/welcome page [Landy](https://landy.website/) that uses Antd, still, it would be the easiest for me to just use it.

Is there any problem with using two different design tools in one project? Does it make the website heavy? Can I optimize it somehow or should I migrate slowly to one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't worry about that, likely you have webpack , rollup, or any other tool that will execute a tree shaking for you so it will only import the used part and not the whole lib

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is ok to use as many libraries you want, but using too many libraries will make your code heavier, so it is recommended to use only 1 UI library

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is ok to use multiple frameworks in a single app. You can use antd or material-ui components with their import statement. Nothing to conflict each others.